# Cannot make Sentry work with Google Cloud Function (python 3.9)

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-functions, sentry

I'm desperately trying to monitor a python 3.9 Google Cloud function exceptions with Sentry, but cannot make it work. Even with the tiny function shown below, exceptions are not ingested into Sentry. I already triple-check the DSN.

```
# main.py
import sentry_sdk
from sentry_sdk.integrations.gcp import GcpIntegration

sentry_sdk.init(
    dsn="https://***@***.ingest.sentry.io/***",
    integrations=[GcpIntegration()]
)

def main(request):
    return 1 / 0
```

```
# requirements.txt
sentry-sdk==1.9.10
```

```
# deploy.sh
gcloud functions deploy test_gcf_sentry \
--trigger-http \
--runtime=python39 \
--entry-point=main \
--memory=1GB \
--security-level=secure-always \
--region=europe-west1
```

Did anyone managed to ingest errors in Sentry from this kind of cloud functions?

Comment: can you refer to this [doc](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/python/guides/gcp-functions/) is it helpful?

Answer (score 1):

GcpIntegration is currently only available for Python 3.7 - check code reference [here](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-python/blob/master/sentry_sdk/integrations/gcp.py#L137).

You can make it work, if you use `serverless_function` decorator:

```
import sentry_sdk
from sentry_sdk.integrations.serverless import serverless_function

sentry_sdk.init(
    dsn="https://***@***.ingest.sentry.io/***",
)

@serverless_function
def main(request):
    return 1 / 0
```